# Zero duration and file compression issue in live video streaming via websocket NodeJS

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, webrtc

Currently working on project where live video streaming required for which i'm using MediaRecorder API for audio / video recording via webcam and speakers.

MediaRecorder API provides blob every 500 ms which we use for writing/appending .webM file on server by websocket NodeJs.

var options = { mimeType: 'video/webm', audioBitsPerSecond : 128000, videoBitsPerSecond : 2500000};

mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

On writing/appending .webM file for say 17 min a .webM file of 6.1 MB is generated on server with below video properties with 0 duration. And on running this .webm

file via HTML5 video element, recording is being played but the time duration for video is not being calculated / displayed.

Duration: 0

**Video:**

Dimension: 640 X 480

Codec: VP8

Framerate: 30 frames per second

Bitrate: N/A

**Audio:**

Codec: Vorbris

Channels: Mono

Sample Rate: 48000 HZ

Bitrate: 239 kbps

Please suggest as why the vidoe duration property value is 0 and how the file size of 6.1 MB can be reduced.